# Why does changing \fontsize in \setkomafont{pagehead} cause overfull \hbox?

Tags: koma-script, fontsize, scrlayer-scrpage

I would like to set the `\fontsize` within `\setkomafont{pagehead}` so that the head looks the same, independent from the document font size. Here is a MWE of what I tried:

```
\documentclass[draft, a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\rohead{%
  \parbox[c][16mm][s]{\textwidth}{%
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip plus 1fil}%
    Header\\
    More header\\
    \\
    \pagemark}}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt} \selectfont}

\begin{document}
  No text here.
\end{document}
```

The result looks fine, but I get

> Overfull \hbox (2.22221pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active

The draft option visualises where these overfull boxes occur:
[image: Header]

After playing around with the MWE, I found out that the error comes from changing the font size within `\setkomafont{pagehead}`. The problem is not, that the `\parbox` in the header is too wide. Also, simply changing the font to `\normalfont` without changing the size, does not result in the overfull box.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the space between `\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}` and `\selectfont`. With this you get a `\parbox` of width `\textwidth` plus a space. And that is more than `\textwidth`. The following works out:

```
\documentclass[draft, a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\rohead{%
  \parbox[c][16mm][s]{\textwidth}{%
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip plus 1fil}%
    Header\\
    More header\\
    \\
    \pagemark}}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
  No text here.
\end{document}
```

To also silence the `\headheight to low` warning, you might change the `\parbox[c][16mm][s]{\textheight}{...}` to `\smash{\parbox[b][16mm][s]{\textheight}{...}}`.

Comment: `\headheight to low` only occurs in the MWE, not in my actual document. Anyway, thanks for also covering this.

Comment: You could also follow the warning and set option `headheight`. Then `typearea` could take care for the large page head while the calculation of margins and typing area.

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes one could, but I supposed the page layout is to OPs liking and he doesn't want to change it but thinks that warning is annoying.